# C# Web Api - Best Practices for Mobile Applications when returning DTO? Multiple Requests or return Everything at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dto

I'm build a mobile app and I am using the WebApi for the backend.  The application allows a user to design their homes virtually.

So, given that each property as a unique number of rooms and room types (i.e., garage, shed, etc.) that are not common to all properties I have created
the idea of a profile.  Remember that I am creating an application that allows you to virtually furnish your home.  Which means that each property has a profile
which translates as follows:

[image: ERD with highlighted tables for discussion]

Of particular interest

I needed to be able to capture this from the UI I am about to build:

Property Profile Summary (referenced below)

```
Id | Name | Quantity
--------------------
1  | Master Bed Room   | 1
2  | Standard Bed Room | 4
3  | Master Bathroom   | 1
4  | Bathroom          | 3
5  | Kitchen           | 1
6  | Living Room       | 1
7  | Garage            | 1
```

here is how I think I want my return DTO to look from the WebApi call. (this describes the first two lines above: (Master Bed Room, Standard Bed Room))

Here assume I have added a King Size Bed in the Master Bedroom and Twin Size Beds in the 4 Standard Bedrooms through the virtual interface

```
{
    Property:
    [
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Sample Property',
            StreetAddress1: '123',
            ...,
            Profile:[
                {
                    Area: {Id: 1, Name: 'Master Bed Room', Type: {...}},
                    Quantity: 1,
                    Profiles: [
                        {
                            Id: 1,
                            LineItems: [
                                Id: 1,
                                Name: 'King Size Bed',
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    Area: {Id: 2, Name: 'Standard Bed Room', Type: {...}},
                    Quantity: 4,
                    Profiles: [
                        {
                            Id: 2,
                            LineItems: [
                                Id: 2,
                                Name: 'Twin Size Bed',
                                ...
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            Id: 3,
                            LineItems: [
                                Id: 3,
                                Name: 'Twin Size Bed',
                                ...
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            Id: 4,
                            LineItems: [
                                Id: 4,
                                Name: 'Twin Size Bed',
                                ...
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            Id: 5,
                            LineItems: [
                                Id: 5,
                                Name: 'Twin Size Bed',
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is as follows:

I am wondering what is the best practice for structuring the WebApi calls or any good article(s) to read.  I can return this entire object based on the user's 
id when the login

The advantage is that in the mobile app (not web app but mobile app) assume a person has two properties at most. (this is only a proof of concept - but I would 
like to know what (if any) is the best practice).  I can also develop the WebApi such that I do the following:

```
User Login -->
 <-- Return Properties
 User Selects Property -->
  <-- Return Property Profile Summary (referenced above)
User wants to drill down on particular room (Standard Room) -->
    <-- Return standard room overview line items (the Profiles[] from the above object)
User want to see the products  (line items) for a given Standard Room (1 of the 4 selected) (Area: {Id: 2} from above object) -->
```

and something like this?

What is the best practice?

Comment: only return on the api call what is specifically needed, otherwise your just adding bloat to the response. You should have specific response models fro each api call where applicable.

Comment: As @Derek said, call just what you need. But one thing you have to keep in mind when developing mobile apps, is that 3g or 4g is not that stable as a wifi connection. So it's good to get all the data you **need** as soon as you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good choice is to adapt your models returned from WEB API to the screens and forms in your app. That means that you should not return entities as is, but convert it to the data transfer objects designed on your app needs.

If your app has a list of some screens, for example "projects" with total rooms count and last modified date, "rooms" with total cost for all furniture, and also contains details page with all products and its quantities in concrete room,  and your database contains few tables like "RoomTypes", "Rooms", "Products", "ProductPrices", "ProductTypes", "Projects" then you already have entities for database objects and should add model classes for your forms:

```
public class ProjectListItem
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; } // you need this field for identification and navigation
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class RoomListItem
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Area { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
}

public class RoomDetailsItem
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // ok, that looks like you can select a base class for this models
    public int Area { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductModel> Products { get; set }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // public decimal BestPrice { get; set; } // you should not add this property because your "details" page not contained this info
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

OK, now your API can looks like next one:

- `/api/v1/Projects` - returns a collection of `ProjectListItem`
- `/api/v1/Projects/{projectId}` - returns a collection of `RoomListItem`
  or a model with this collection inside
- `/api/v1/Projects/{projectId}/{roomId}` - returns a `RoomDetailsItem`

You need to convert your entities to this models in your API. Stored model should be optimized on your app needs (fast retrieving or avoidance of duplication) and your presentation model should be optimized on your application requirements.